# How do I grip stainless steel pipes for threading?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, central-heating

I am about to install a new central heating system powered by a wood pellet boiler. To obtain maximum corrosion resistance, I have chosen PEX pipes for the low temperature underfloor heating circuits and stainless steel pipes (AISI 304) for the remaining parts of the system.

The issue is that my vise cannot get a good grip on the stainless steel pipes because the surface is significantly smoother than ordinary galvanized steel pipe.

Therefore I ask for better solutions to secure stainless steel pipes while doing pipe threading.

Answer (score 2):

You've chosen a real challenge, actually fitting threaded pipe.  Hardly anyone does that anymore.

Stainless isn't harder than other steels.  You just need to use a pipe wrench or pipe vise.  This will gouge the pipe, but that is normal in pipefitting.   If you want no-gouge, you can try rubber gripper pads as are often used on kitchens.

If you're dealing in thinwall tubing, different story.

Comment: I recall that about 25 years ago I tried to drill into some 1/8" thick stainless steel plating and got nowhere. Of course I cannot remember if I used the right kind of drill bit. Are you sure that stainless steel is not harder than ordinary (mild?) steel?

Comment: From what blacksmith37 says, it work hardens like a freak.  So if you don't come into it with just the right feed and speed, it will harden up on ya.

Answer (score 2):

Stainless steel,like 304, actually starts out softer than carbon steel : But, it cold works much faster.  So if a cutting tool slips against the SS it hardens very quickly and may then be nearly impossible to cut ( for an amateur). If your vice is big enough , the other problem may be your cutter has slipped, hardening the SS. Then much more torque is required, twisting the pipe out of the vice. Also . I would look on the net to find good cutting oil ( not the same as lube oil).
I would suggest copper tubing or pipe , it is much easier to work with and should handle nearly any water system. If you are working with  stainless steel or copper in smaller sizes like 1/2 inch , I would suggest compression fittings instead of pipe threads.

Answer (score 2):

I have to ask, why are you using stainless steel pipe? Unless the pipe is actually being used in a corrosive environment, stainless steel pipe is a waste of money. If the piping is to connect to the heating coil or heating apparatus in the boiler, then steel pipe, either schedule 40 or schedule 80 or copper tubing will suffice. Also what size pipe are we talking about?  A good explanation of your project would be helpful. Standard pipe dies are not for threading stainless steel. That uses special dies.

Comment: Worth adding that threaded stainless steel fittings such as elbows and couplings are extremely expensive.  Using stainless for this application is very difficult, very expensive, and non-standard, which may cause problems down the road.  If you're determined to use stainless steel, it's much easier and probably cheaper to use tubing and compression fittings.

Answer (score 1):

You could try taping the pipe where you want to grip it. Duct tape wrapped a few times might suffice. With a vise grip or channel locks it might give you the purchase you need to turn the pipe for threading.

Comment: +1 for tape.  You could also try painters' tape, as it has a fairly rough texture and isn't terribly hard to remove (although it might not adhere that well to stainless).

Comment: @ChrisM. I Had thought of masking/painters at first, but I was worried about the grip. Painter's is specifically low tack.

Comment: That's true.  I was thinking painters specifically because low-tack wouldn't leave a residue on the pipe or be difficult to remove after  But it might be *too* low-tack for stainless.

Comment: If you are installing a closed loop hot water system, stainless steel is unnecessary, Black iron or copper would be preferred since there will be no corrosion. Please explain why you chose to install stainless steel pipe.

Comment: @d.george You should make this comment under the question and not my answer

Comment: sorry I stuck it in the wrong place. I do not understand why anyone would use stainless pipe.

Comment: One more comment,, you need special pipe dies to properly thread stainless steel pipe.

Comment: @d.george Seriously, delete the comments here and repost them under the question

Comment: chill out! chill out! chill out! don't get your knickers twisted.